# My files are all missing from my portfolio site? React JS - GH-Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, framer-motion, portfolio

Decided to come back and improve my portfolio site after a couple of months. However, my files all seem to be missing? I don't see any additional changes or pull requests, and going back to my past commit, it seems very different that how it was before.

It was a react js app, with react router, and animations (from framer motion) and now all I see are the static files (logos, etc) and 3 static js files that look nonsensical.

I've tried googling and looking for a similar problem but I can't find it. Forgive me, it's been sometime since I've looked back into a project like this. Please help!

Here is the repo: https://github.com/sanchezbarry/portfolio

I had a bunch of jsx files that served the website (sanchezbarry.com)